# Finding and Storing JSON Nested Arrays When Names Unknown

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere here, I have not found it if it has been. I have valid JSON:

```
{
    "main": [
        {
            "Example1": [
                {
                    "Example1_Var02": "5",
                    "Example1_Var09": "443",
                    "Example1_Var27": "23",
                    "Example1_Var01": "31"
                }
            ],
            "Example2": [
                {
                    "Example2_Var99": "2",
                    "Example2_Var84": "344",
                    "Example2_Var46": "56",
                    "Example2_Var03": "78"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

whose names are unknown to me and/or will change regularly, except for the super key of "main." Assuming a successful `$.ajax()` call that returns "data," e.g. `success: function(data) {` , I would like to break out each nested array into localstorage without needing to know their key names, as I may never know them. But as it is, I cannot get something where I know those sub-array names to work. This:

```
for(var key in data){
   localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data[key]));
}
```

will create a single localstorage instance of "main". But this (and other variations):

```
for(var key in data){
   localStorage.setItem(key.Example1[0], JSON.stringify(data[key.Example1]));
}
```

returns an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined". And since I cannot accomplish this with a known subarray key name, doing it at an abstract, anonymous level is more challenging still. How can I simply output whatever nested arrays happen to be contained in "main" to separate local storage without necessarily knowing their names in the JSON? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where in the world did the "Hole1Info" come from? I mean, that appears nowhere in the JSON.

Comment: also if you know there's a key "main", why not just do `for (var key in data.main)` ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Right you are, @Pointy, my apologies -- I have edited the answer to remove that instance. For you and Felix Kling, I may know there is a super array named "main," but no knowledge of the arrays it contains. I'm trying to get a completely anonymous way of finding out what those arrays contained in "main" are and outputting whatever those arrays are to localstorage, a different implementation than Felix' undeniably awesome canonical answer about nested data structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Pointy pointed out, if you can always expect main to be there and the structure of the object is predictable (even if the names and data aren't) you can use a `for...in` statement to iterate over the object:

```
for(var outer in x.main){ 
    for(var inner_key in x.main[outer]){ 
        localStorage.setItem(inner_key, JSON.stringify(x.main[outer][inner_key]));

    }
}

console.log(localStorage.getItem('Example1'));
// "[{"Example1_Var02":"5","Example1_Var09":"443","Example1_Var27":"23","Example1_Var01":"31"}]"
```

Comment: Absolutely what I was looking for -- my knowledge of these syntaxes when working with objects is woefully limited, so truly appreciate whatever help I can get. Thanks, Rob!